# $13$ integers from $S = \{150 , 151 , ...... , 173 \}$. Any choice of $13$ integers will have a pair of integers whose difference is $3$.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

We have to choose $13$ integers from this set $S = \{150 , 151 , 152 , 153 , .............. 172 , 173 \}$.

I have to show that for any choice of $13$ integers there will be a pair of integers whose difference is $3$.

I was trying to apply Pegion Hole principle. But I am not being able to do so.

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Can you define $S$ more clearly? Should that be $\{150,151,\dots, 173\}$, or is that really $152$ after $150$?

Comment: Similar to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903357/pigeon-hole-principle-to-prove-a-b-9-in-subset/3903464#3903464). Partition the set as in my answer. $\{(150, 151, ... 155).(156,... 161),...\}$ etc. $3\cdot4+1$ is straightforward PHP.

Comment: There are $24 = 2 \times (13-1)$ numbers in the set (typo aside). This prompts us the put the numbers in $S$ in pairs.

Comment: Please have a look now @Hendrix

Comment: This link does not seem to have my answer. @cosmo5

Comment: Consider $3$ sets/rows/vectors of numbers (let $a=150$):

$$A = (a, a+3, a+6, a+9, \ldots, a+21), \\
B = (a+1, a+4, a+7, a+10, \ldots, a+22), \\
C = (a+2, a+5, a+8, a+11, \ldots, a+23).$$

If we choose $13$ numbers, then one of the sets ($A,B,C$) provides at least $5$ numbers (according to pigeonhole principle).

And that's impossible to chose $5$ numbers out of $8$ to have no neighboring numbers.
These neighboring numbers will have difference $3$.

Comment: @Oleg567 I think you should go ahead and put that as an answer.

Comment: You may write this in Answer. @Oleg567

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $3$ sets/rows/vectors of numbers (let $a=150$): 
$A = (a, a+3, a+6, a+9, \ldots, a+21)$, 
$B = (a+1, a+4, a+7, a+10, \ldots, a+22)$, 
$C = (a+2, a+5, a+8, a+11, \ldots, a+23)$.

If we choose $13$ numbers, then one of the sets ($A,B,C$) provides at least $5$ numbers (according to pigeonhole principle).

And that's impossible to choose $5$ numbers out of $8$ to have no neighboring numbers.
These neighboring numbers will have difference $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Partition into sets of size *double* the difference, $3$.

$$ \{150,151,152,153,154,155\} , \{156,\ldots,161\}, \ldots , \{168\ldots,173\}  $$

These are $4$ sets. In each set we have $3$ pairs differing by $3$.

E.g., ${(150,153), (151,154),(152,155)}$.

Hence we have $12$ pairs of numbers differing by $3$.

Any choice of $13$ integers would include two numbers from same pair. Hence proved.